Derivation of Inequality 3 from Inequality 4 Using Bayes' Theorem in "Scheduling Multithreaded Computations by Work Stealing"
In the paper "Scheduling Multithreaded Computations by Work Stealing" under the section "Atomic accesses and the recycling game", it is mentioned that inequality 4:
$$ \Pr \left\{ x_{ir} = 1 \mid \bigwedge_{(i',r') \in S'} (x_{i'r'} = 1) \right\} \leq 1/P $$
can be derived from Bayes' theorem to yield inequality 3:
$$ \Pr \left\{ \bigwedge_{(i,r) \in S} (x_{ir} = 1) \right\} \leq P^{-|S|} $$
How is this derivation done?
